# Ford Fiesta 1.4 TDCi Oil Leak

Tags: ford, oil-leak, turbocharger

I have a Ford Fiesta 1.4 TDCi 2006 model and I recently did a head gasket change. Now there is a oil leak from the engine, behind the turbo, i cant seem to find the source, but it looks bad. Can anyone help diagnose the problem
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it is coming from behind the turbo, I'd suspect the oil return line coming from the turbo going back to the sump. I can see the results of the oil leak, but not sure where it's coming from in the pictures. You may need to pull some of the air ducting/hoses away so you can get a better look.

Comment: i'll upload new pictures soon, so you can get a better view, also i notice an air stream coming from the engine(near the turbo but not from the turbo i guess)  towards the front(Grill) . will upload the picture soon

Comment: Can you better explain "air stream"? Or will the picture show what you're talking about? Looking forward to seeing the pics.

Comment: I have uploaded the new image, please check it,

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 please check the new images

Comment: What was the problem ? I have the same issue .

Comment: Did you ever resolve the issue?  If so, what did you do?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21711)

Comment: sorry guys to reply so late, the issue is that there is oil coming from the breather pipe connected to the rocker cover, and I still haven't resolved it yet, I don't know why there is a pipe there in the first place? any idea of a breather pipe, that to the head rocker cover.?

Answer (score 2):

In the second picture, at the bottom on the right, you can see the hex shaped top of the housing (where it says "25 Nm"). Check at the base of that, which appears to be a filter housing. Also, at the bottom of this housing. There appears to be a some kind of cooler or heat interchanger. Check around that. If there is a spray coming up from a leak, this would be the area I'd be looking at.

Get some carb cleaner (two cans if needed) and get the entire area clean. You want to get as much (if not all) of the oil off of there which you can. When it is as clean as you can get it, you'll want to try and start the car without any of the ducting replaced. You may get some lights on the dash because of it, but this shouldn't be an issue. You can blank the codes later with a hand scanner or take it somewhere to have them taken out. You may not get the car started, but what you are looking for (or someone else, this is going to take two people) is to see where the oil is coming from. Look in the area where I'm suggesting and this will give you a good indication. If it's spurting or spraying up, I'll bet it will be self evident quite quickly. This will give you a good indication of what you'll need to do next and which parts you're going to need. If the car does start, DO NOT RUN IT LONGER THAN NECESSARY! Only crank it as long as you need to if you can see the leak. Also, wear some eye protection just in case it is spurting a bit more than what you might imagine. If the engine is warm, you'll want to ensure you have your arms covered and some type of gloves on ... hot oil can be nasty on bare skin.

I'm sorry I cannot give you better information than this, but hopefully this will lead you to your leak and maybe help you to get it fixed.

Comment: Let me do these instructions first. and get back to you. thanks man

Comment: looks like the oil filter is clean and good, the issues is with oil entering the turbo, I have no idea if that is meant to be,

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a VERY old thread but I just wanted to say I have a U.K. specification 2005 1.6L TDCi Ghia. The leak for me came from a historical engine oil filter cover that was not secured on properly. Oil came out from the seams. Just tightened it up and it went away.

It that isn't the problem then check all the lines which go to and return from the Turbo. I found another historical engine oil and looks very similar to these pictures you show. The turbo had been replaced but 1 or 2 lines weren't connected back properly so a leak occurred. The garage didn't bother cleaning it up so it's still there when you look at the engine. The turbo had failed due to a lack of oil lubrication in the first place I think.

Hope that may help and did you fix the problem too?